# Настройка graphql в приложении nextjs

Tags: nextjs, graphql

Решил познакомиться с graphql, пошел по туториалам ([тут](https://www.prisma.io/blog/fullstack-nextjs-graphql-prisma-2-fwpc6ds155#defining-a-schema) и [тут](https://youtu.be/jXqkJARfWiQ)). Использую версию nextjs 13.4.19, app router. Создал приложение, подключил базовую конфигурацию prisma. Пытаюсь подключить graphql используя [graphql-yoga](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/yoga-server/docs/integrations/integration-with-nextjs), где приведен пример как это должно быть.

Структура папок следующая:

```
prisma
    schema.prisma
src
    app
       page.tsx
       api/route.ts
```

route.ts

```
import { createSchema, createYoga } from 'graphql-yoga';
import prisma from '../../../prisma/client';

const { handleRequest } = createYoga({
    schema: createSchema({
        typeDefs: /* GraphQL */ `
            type Query {
                hello: String
            }
        `,
    resolvers: {
        Query: {
            hello: () => 'world',
        },
    },
}),

graphqlEndpoint: '/api/graphql',
fetchAPI: { Response },
});

export { handleRequest as GET, handleRequest as POST };
```

page.tsx

```
async function getHello() {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/api`);
    return res.json();
}

export default async function About() {
    const data = await getHello();
    console.log(data);

    return (
        <main className={styles.main}>
            <h1>About page</h1>
        </main>
    );
}
```

Допустим пишу следующий запрос:

```
query Query{
    hello
}
```

Получаю кучу ошибок в консоле:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
at async invokeRequest (D:\...\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\server-ipc\invoke- 
request.js:17:12)
at async invokeRender (D:\...\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:254:29)
at async requestHandler (D:\...\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:475:24)
at async Server.<anonymous> (D:\...\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start- 
server.js:117:13) {
cause: RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length 
header
  at write (D:\...\app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\undici\index.js:1:67105)
  at _resume (D:\...\app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\undici\index.js:1:66726)
  at resume (D:\...\app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\undici\index.js:1:65413)
  at connect (D:\...\app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\undici\index.js:1:65301) {
code: 'UND_ERR_REQ_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH'
    }
}
```

Подскажите что я делаю не правильно и как делать нужно. Может я вообще не ту либу выбрал или не правильно использую???

Comment: В консолИ, а не в консолЕ.